# Append html with JQuery, Input value has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading a html form with an AJAX call. The return is some input html code. 
If I make an alert of the code, I've got this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[Point][lat]" id="PointLat" value="45820545077811445" autocomplete="off" />
```

After adding the html code to the page (with jQuerys' `html()` method), my source code looks like this :

```
<input id="PointLat" type="hidden" value="0" autocomplete="off" name="data[Point][lat]">
```

I'm running out of ideas here ! 
Thanks !

Comment: So what is the type of input element? `hidden` or `text`?

Comment: How are you looking at the source?

Comment: Well, In the first, you have type being declared twice, so that's why you're getting type='hidden'.

Comment: It's a last minute change. Both are hidden. But actually, hidden or text, does the same.
I'm showing the result with an "alert()", that give me the first one. I'm looking at the second one with Firebug on FF, and the Developpers tools on Google Chrome.

Comment: Nevermind, a function that dynamically change thoses values was call after that, when it shouldn't.
Thanks for considering my questions.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in exactly similar way you have tried... there is no way the code which you have put up is changing it....

There surely exists some code.. which changes the value of `PointLat` search for something `$("#PointLat").val(0)` or  `$("#PointLat").val('')` or something similar...

Please post the code update as mentioned by @cole

Comment: Nevermind, a function that dynamically change thoses values was call after that, when it shouldn't.
Thanks for considering my questions.
Regards.

Comment: glad it helped... please learn to debug in firebug by putting breakpoints it helps a lot... to understand where the values are changing and how the code flow works... u mind if you click the up button if this answer was useful... so than contributors can spend their worthy time to help others... rather than revisiting this question....

Comment: I don't use Breakpoints in Firebug enough, but it's actually a good idea.

You know, it was one of this time, or more the time fly, the less you have a clear vision, and the more crazy you get. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please append your javascript that makes your ajax call and handles the returned value. Without that the only advice I can give you is that append() appends the html directly to the dom as you passed it in.

Comment: Yeah i know, i tried with append, it does the same. I was thinking that maybe Firefox was loading the last known result, that's why i've added the "autocomplete=off", but still the same.
I don't understand why my value is coming to 0

Comment: Sorry, I meant update your original post with your javascript code.